# CORS and pre-flight OPTIONS - Disable authentication for single page

Tags: 2010, authentication, cors

I'm struggling with a `CORS` request to our `SharePoint 2010` server.
It seems that the `CORS` request to the SharePoint server requires authentication, which the pre-flight of the `CORS`-request does not provide. So the answer from SharePoint seems to be a `401 Unauthorized` for the pre-flight, so the whole request fails. 
Now I'm searching, how I can disable authentication for a single SharePoint page or if it is even possible?
Does anybody know a way to disable the authentication just for a single page and not on the `farm` level?

Here is a link to my `CORS` request issue on Stackoverflow for everybody, who is interested in details for the `CORS` request.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61053253/how-to-setup-cors-setup-correctly?noredirect=1#comment108010958_61053253

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue, by using a `simple request` of `CORS`.
By using a `simple request` no pre-flight is being done and so the request does not fail.
See this link for more details about `simple requests`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS